# Rollback updates from audit log in CRM Online 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I didn't think it would happen to me but it did:

I was debugging / testing my mass updater console application and after the program successfully terminated I realized that in my app configuration file it was pointing to a production environment, not a test environment. That said and done, about 200 contacts' information went a bit off track. Thankfully though I was only updating text fields and not lookup fields. There is an audit log turned on for contacts so I can see exact fields that are changed.

This may not be programming related question but is there any way to "roll back" those updates from audit logs? If not straight from the UI have any of you ever done something similar with code? I can easily find those contacts using "modified date" and "modified by" information. Can I somehow retrieve audit logs for those contacts and compare old and new value and rollback the old value if necessary?

Comment: as far as I know no way to do an automatic rollback and I didn't see around tools to help you with this problem. However writing some code that will check the audit and restore the value it's possible

Comment: I found this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309735.aspx) and I was able to create a program that can read audit logs and retrieve old values. I'll post my code here later to help others who might face the same  situation. What a mess though. I also run to this (https://crm2013auditundo.codeplex.com/) but in my case I needed something faster.

Answer (score 0):

As I promised here's the code that worked for me. It worked for me because I knew that no updates were made after my mass updater. If I wouldn't knew that extra checks would have been necessary. Anyway, hope this helps

```
SystemUser sysUser = crmProxy.SystemUserSet.Where(su => su.DomainName == "my-value").Single();
DateTime modified = new DateTime(2015, 5, 27);
List<Contact> contacts = crmProxy.ContactSet.Where(c => c.ModifiedBy.Id == sysUser.Id && c.ModifiedOn.Value >= modified).ToList();
foreach(Contact con in contacts) {

    RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryRequest changeRequest = new RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryRequest();
    changeRequest.Target = new EntityReference(Contact.EntityLogicalName, con.Id);
    RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryResponse changeResponse = (RetrieveRecordChangeHistoryResponse)crmProxy.Execute(changeRequest);                    
    AuditDetailCollection details = changeResponse.AuditDetailCollection;

    foreach (AttributeAuditDetail detail in details.AuditDetails) {
        AttributeCollection auditBase = detail.AuditRecord.Attributes;
        if ((DateTime)auditBase["createdon"] >= modified) {
            AttributeCollection oldBase = detail.OldValue.Attributes;
            AttributeCollection newBase = detail.OldValue.Attributes;

            Contact contactToBeRolledBack = new Contact() { Id = con.Id };
            if (oldBase.Contains("firstname")) {
                contactToBeRolledBack.FirstName = (string)oldBase["firstname"];
            } else { contactToBeRolledBack.FirstName = ""; }

            crmProxy.Update(contactToBeRolledBack);

            break;
        }                        
    }
}
```